# How to share Twonky 7 library (running in NAS) over internet?

Tags: nas, dynamic-dns

**The problem:**

I had funplug & Twonky Server 7 running on my Dlink DNS320 ([guide](http://nas-tweaks.net/384/installation-of-twonky-server-7-on-nas-devices/)).

Now I want to share my Twonky library over internet using dyndns but failed.

**Attempted:**

I modified [dyndns] section in the file: /ffp/opt/twonky/twonkyserver-default.ini

```
dyndns=http://myown.dyndns.org:50001
```

but the library links still show local IP, for e.g:

```
http://192.168.0.100:9000/disk/DLNA-PNWMVMED_BASE-OP01-FLAGS01700000/O0$3$27I157706.wmv
```

**Things I tried:**

- Restart Twonky
- Reinstall Twonky
- Rename twonkyserver-default.ini → twonkyvision-default.ini (as some forums suggested)

No chance. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your twonky config.js to allow relative root path. It will output the URL as `http://<your_host_file>/<url_to_your_files`.

[Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20131218200547/http://community.twonky.com/twonky/topics/how_to_share_twonky_library_over_internet_using_dyndns)

Comment: Link is unfortunately dead.